# When will AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification be posted?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

In Apple's sample code "[AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)", AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification is added to NSNotificationCenter, but its callback "subjectAreaDidChange" is never called on my test. I wonder when will this notification be posted by system?

It's added by the following code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(subjectAreaDidChange:)
                                             name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification
                                           object:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
```

And the header file AVCaptureDevice.h of AVFoundation is as follows:

```
@constant  AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification
@abstract
   Posted when the instance of AVCaptureDevice has detected a substantial change to the 
   video subject area.
@discussion
   Clients may observe the AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification to know when an
   instance of AVCaptureDevice has detected a substantial change to the video subject area.
   This notification is only sent if you first set subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled to
   YES.
```

That's all my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set

> [[self videoDeviceInput] device].subjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = YES;

Comment: Does this need to be set multiple times? Because for me, I set this before registering the delegate, but the delegate sometimes doesn't fire if I move the device fast (change the visible subject fast).